# How to reuse an entity to work with different components

Tags: vhdl

I'm reasonably new to vhdl and wondering what the best way is to manage the following situation / pattern:

Say I have an entity A whose architecture instantiates a component B. I would then like to reuse A but this time instantiate a component C in the place of B. C has a completely different functionality to B. B and C may have different sized ports, however the functionality of A is such that it can handle the different port sizes, using, say, generics and generate statements. Essentially A is like a container for either component B, C or maybe D, E, F etc. It maybe performs some logic/buffering on the inputs and outputs of B, C etc. in a way that is common for all these components.

I have read about configurations and my understanding is that I can instantiate a component in A (call it Z), and then link it's entity to different architectures using configurations. It seems not many people use this feature of vhdl.

Are configurations the right way to go for this situation?

Ideally, I would like all of the parameters in the design to depend ultimately on the architecture chosen for Z so that the architecture dictates the port sizes of the entity its linked to (Z), and in turn the port sizes of Z dictate the parameters of A and finally these parameters dictate the port sizes of A. Is this possible?

(I am using 'parameterisation' in the general sense to mean a way of configuring a design. Generics, packages, 'range attributes etc would all be examples of parameterisation)

A pseudocode example of what I mean is below. The values in capitals should depend on the architecture chosen for Z.

```
entity A is

    port
    (
        clk             : in std_logic;
        reset           : in std_logic;
        inputs          : in std_logic_vector(SOME_WIDTH_A_IN - 1 downto 0);
        outputs         : out std_logic_vector(SOME_WIDTH_A_OUT - 1 downto 0);
    );

end A;

architecture A_arch of A is

    component Z

        port
        (
            clock       : in std_logic;
            inputs      : std_logic_vector(SOME_WIDTH_Z_IN - 1 downto 0);
            ouputs      : std_logic_vector(SOME_WIDTH_Z_OUT - 1 downto 0)
        );

    end component;

begin

    for i in 1 to SOME_VALUE generate
        -- whatever logic/buffering we want to perform on the inputs    
    end generate;

    for i in 1 to SOME_VALUE generate
        -- whatever logic/buffering we want to perform on the outputs
    end generate;

    instance: Z   
        port map(
            clock => clk,
            inputs => --output of logic/buffering above 
            outputs => -- input of logic/buffering above
        );

end A_arch;
```

I may be thinking about this the wrong way - Essentially I would like to avoid having to copy/paste the 'container' entity A to work with different components B, C etc. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "module" is a verilog term. Use "entity". You should draw this in a schematic. What do you mean with "container"? It is a very broad concept. You're also using "parameters" and "filter" which are not VHDL concepts. To summerize: I find ik hard to understand your question. Maybe write some pseudocode or so?

Comment: Thanks for looking, just working on an edit

Comment: Configurations are what you are looking for, I think. I would definitely use them.

Comment: Is it possible to derive the values in capitals in the pseudocode directly from the architecture chosen for Z? Or must A have prior knowledge of these values (ie do I have to provide these values separately as generics to the entity A)

Comment: You can do all this with generics and give them values in the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want your components B,C,D, etc... to do exactly the same except for different port sizes. The best approach to do this is with GENERIC.  Let's say your other entity (let's call it INNER_ENTITY) is configurable n-bit wide double flip flop (can be used to resolve metastability).
Here is the example code for OUTER_ENTITY and INNER_ENTITY:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity OUTER_ENTITY is
    port (
        CLK     : in    std_logic;
        RST     : in    std_logic;
        PORT_A  : in    std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        PORT_B  : in    std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
        SUM_A_B : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture RTL_OUTER_ENTITY of OUTER_ENTITY is
    signal PORT_A_INNER : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal PORT_B_INNER : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);

    component INNER_ENTITY
        generic (PORT_SIZE : integer);
        port (
            CLK      : in   std_logic;
            RST      : in   std_logic;
            PORT_IN  : in   std_logic_vector(PORT_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
            PORT_OUT : out  std_logic_vector(PORT_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
        );
    end component INNER_ENTITY;

begin

    SUM_A_B <= PORT_A_INNER + PORT_B_INNER;

    INNER_7_BIT : INNER_ENTITY
        generic map (PORT_SIZE => 7)
        port map (
            CLK         => CLK,
            RST         => RST,
            PORT_IN     => PORT_A,
            PORT_OUT    => PORT_A_INNER
        );

    INNER_14_BIT : INNER_ENTITY
        generic map (PORT_SIZE => 14)
        port map (
            CLK         => CLK,
            RST         => RST,
            PORT_IN     => PORT_B,
            PORT_OUT    => PORT_B_INNER
        );
end RTL_OUTER_ENTITY;   

entity INNER_ENTITY
    generic (PORT_SIZE : integer);
    port (
        CLK      : in   std_logic;
        RST      : in   std_logic;
        PORT_IN  : in   std_logic_vector(PORT_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
        PORT_OUT : out  std_logic_vector(PORT_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
    );
end entity;

architecture RTL_INNER_ENTITY of INNER_ENTITY is

    signal  PORT_X :  std_logic_vector(PORT_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
begin

    process(CLK, RST)
    begin
        if RST = '1' then
            PORT_OUT <= (OTHERS => '0');
            PORT_X   <= (OTHERS => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
            PORT_OUT <= PORT_X;
            PORT_X <= PORT_IN;
        end if;
    end process;
end RTL_INNER_ENTITY;
```

Please note that I did not compile this code so it might have some minor syntax errors but it should give you an overview to how GENERICs might be used to do what you want.

Comment: I added this before I saw your example code but I'm sure you can see what I did. Generics can also be used in FOR LOOP statements

Comment: Thanks for answering, however B and C in fact have different functionalities. In my case they are different audio processing algorithms. I have edited again to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah ok, then I would use a generic in ENTITY A to specifify the functionality (according to what you said the port size is not deterministic whether to use B or C). Then use an IF...THEN...GENERATE to use B or C based on the generic.

Comment: The problem with that is that with a large number of possible functionalities the architecture Z would become a bit unwieldy no? Also where would we get the value of SOME_VALUE in the pseudocode? We could calculate it in A (if functionality B then SOME_VALUE = WHATEVER) however this means that A must be edited every time there is a change to B (or C or D etc). And that is what I am trying to avoid as mistakes will be easily introduced that way.

Comment: The IF THEN GENERATE construct will let you have different processes based of the generic value. So, YES. You can also use a regular IF THEN inside a process. But I believe that would be more confusing.

Comment: My bad - I deleted the comment you just responded to.

Comment: That's ok. Here is the answer to your latest question: the IF THEN GENERATE would go into entity A. You will not have an entity Z. Just entities A,B,C.. in seperate files. the IF THEN GENERATE you will pick which ENTITY to use based on the generic value.

Comment: Ah ok, that solves the SOME_VALUE problem (as that can be derived directly from the port size of the generated entity) but now A will become unwieldy if there are, say, 30 different options for functionality. I really wanted to be able to code A and then not have to touch the file in the case of adding new B, C etc functionalities. Perhaps there is no way around that.

Comment: There are two generics involved. One is port size. The other is functionality. The two generics are independent from each other. The functionality generic will dictate whether to use B,C,D, etc... The enitty B, for example, will accomodate any port size based on the generic port size.

Comment: Ok. We may not use the port size to determine B or C (as you said), however the use of B or C does dictate the port size. What you are saying is that A must have prior knowledge of the port size, correct? Also thank you for answering all these questions - should this be in chat?